# Working with html 5 canvas drawing

Tags: html, canvas

I want similar functionality for drawing image with smooth curves in html canvas. Can somebody tel me how to get such smooth curves?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used [Smooth.js](https://github.com/osuushi/Smooth.js) for a projet and I was pretty convinced by it.
See some examples [here](http://osuushi.github.com/plotdemo016.html).

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend one of the bests in this category:

http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification/

http://d3js.org/